# discord bot python delete channel gives an error

Tags: python, discord, command, discord.py, bots

I tried to make a command that deletes nuke channels against a nuke bot,
this is my code:

```
async def inferno(ctx,problem):
    if problem == ("channelnuke"):
        channel == ("Nuke-channel")
        await ctx.send("okay solving problem")
        await ctx.send("Guard on, every nuke channel will be instant deleted")
        while True:
            
            await channel.delete()
```

But it gives an error that discord has no attribute delete

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: module 'discord.channel' has no attribute 'delete'
```

Does anyone know how it should be done?

Comment: What's the purpose of that while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly I can't comment on the previous answer because of my insufficient reputation. so here is the updated code on the previous answer, this should work now.

```py
@client.command()
async def inferno(ctx, problem):
    if problem == "channelnuke":
        channel = ctx.channel   # the previous answer had put (==) instead of (=)
        await ctx.send("okay solving problem")
        await ctx.send("Guard on, every nuke channel will be instant deleted")
        await channel.delete()
```

if you want to add channels, you can do it by putting the channel as an optional arguements:

```py
@client.command()
async def inferno(ctx, problem, channel : commands.TextChannelConverter = None): # we will put the channel into an optional arguments by doing = None
    if channel == None: # it will find the channel if you didn't specify the channel
        channel = ctx.channel
    await ctx.send("okay solving problem")
    if problem == "channelnuke":
        await channel.delete()
```

the TextChannelConverter will look at the channel, you can use id, the channel name, or mention the channel and it should work, more info about it will be below.

[TextChannelConverter Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.TextChannelConverter)

Thank me later :D

Comment: Thank you Pixie, do you also know how I can specify a name of a channel?

Comment: I added the command now, it should work :D, look at the answer I edited

Comment: Thanks, how do i make a loop of this?

Answer (score 0):

```py
async def inferno(ctx, problem):
    if problem == "channelnuke":
        channel == ctx.channel
        await channel.delete()
        await ctx.send("okay solving problem")
        await ctx.send("Guard on, every nuke channel will be instant deleted")
```

Comment: this doesnt work still gives the some error